# Separating concerns for NpgsqlConnection

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have an architecture where multiple repository classes implement different queries and commands that are run against the database. I would like to separate the concern of "connecting to the database" + "running queries" and "providing a query to run" + "treating the result". I've written a Connection class that is then passed as a constructor argument to the repositories like such:

```
public class PostgreSqlConnection
{
    private string connectionString;

    public PostgreSqlConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public async Task<NpgsqlDataReader> ExecuteQueryCommand(NpgsqlCommand command)
    {
        using NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Prepare();
        return await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    }

    public async Task ExecuteNonQueryCommand(NpgsqlCommand command)
    {
        using NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Prepare();
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

The instantiation would look something like this:

```
PostgreSqlConnection connection = new PostgreSqlConnection("...connection string");
IRepositoryA repA = new PostgreSqlRepositoryA(connection);
IRepositoryB repB = new PostgreSqlRepositoryB(connection);
```

Code duplication aside, this doesn't work since in the query case, the connection would be disposed of at the end of the `ExecuteQueryCommand` method and the reader would stop working.

Removing the `using` statement would fix this but from what I gather that is not good practice. Writing a `Dispose` / `Disconnect` method that I could call in the repositories would be something that would also work but it's not the repository's job to dispose of the connection.

How could I go about keeping the concerns separated and disposing of the items properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what here can help is a Unit of Work pattern. Basically, with `UnitOfWork` class  you handle the connection, repository instances and transactions if needed (in case you are saving data to DB). You also have a flexibility to open a connection/transaction and then execute multiple commands across many repositories and in the end you either commit or rollback the transaction, or in case of pure reading you just close the connection using `IDisposable` pattern.

`UnitOfWork` class will handle the connection part, your `BaseRepository` (abstract class) will have your generic execute methods and it will handle the execution of query/command. The concrete repositories (A and B in your case) will inherit from `BaseRepository`, just prepare the commands/queries and call the Execute methods from a `BaseRepository`. Their responsibility is basically to prepare the query/command and to handle the result from Execute methods.

Please review the code because I don't have Postgres database and I can't test it 100%. I hope this is enough for you to give you a direction and the main idea behind the approach.

Here is the idea:

1. Implement `UnitOfWork` where you manange the connection, transaction if needed and repository instances.

   ```
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
        {
        private PostgreSqlRepositoryA _postgreSqlRepositoryA;
        private PostgreSqlRepositoryB _postgreSqlRepositoryB;
        private NpgsqlConnection _sqlConnection;
        private NpgsqlTransaction _sqlTransaction;
        private bool _disposed;

        public UnitOfWork(string connectionString, bool withTransaction)
        {
            _sqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            _sqlConnection.Open();

            if (withTransaction)
                _sqlTransaction = _sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public PostgreSqlRepositoryA PostgreSqlRepositoryA 
        { 
            get
            { 
                if(_postgreSqlRepositoryA == null)
                {
                    _postgreSqlRepositoryA = new PostgreSqlRepositoryA(_sqlConnection);
                }

                return _postgreSqlRepositoryA;
            } 
        }

        public PostgreSqlRepositoryB PostgreSqlRepositoryB
        {
            get
            {
                if (_postgreSqlRepositoryB == null)
                {
                    _postgreSqlRepositoryB = new PostgreSqlRepositoryB(_sqlConnection);
                }

                return _postgreSqlRepositoryB;
            }
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            // hanlde using try-catch
            if(_sqlTransaction != null)
            {
                _sqlTransaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            if (_sqlTransaction != null)
            {
                _sqlTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                if (_sqlTransaction != null)
                {
                    _sqlTransaction.Rollback(); // or throw an Exception for an opened transaction
                }

                if (_sqlConnection != null)
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Close();
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                this._disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   2. Then what you need is a `BaseRepository` which will hold your "generic" methods for query/command execution:

      ```
       public abstract class BaseRepository
       {
           protected NpgsqlConnection _sqlConnection;

           public BaseRepository(NpgsqlConnection sqlConnection)
           {
               this._sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
           }

           public async Task<NpgsqlDataReader> ExecuteQueryCommand(NpgsqlCommand command)
           {
               command.Connection = _sqlConnection;
               command.Prepare();
               return await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
           }

           public async Task ExecuteNonQueryCommand(NpgsqlCommand command)
           {
               command.Connection = _sqlConnection;
               command.Prepare();
               await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
           }
       }
      ```
2. Your concrete repository implementation will look like this (I didn't bother with handling the reader, you can add that part):

   ```
   public class PostgreSqlRepositoryB : BaseRepository
    {
        public PostgreSqlRepositoryB(NpgsqlConnection sqlConnection)
            : base(sqlConnection)
        {}

        public async Task<int> GetCountB()
        {
            using (var sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandText = "select count(1) from TableB";

                var reader = await ExecuteQueryCommand(sqlCommand);

                // TODO: handle reader
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. And the in the end you will use it from your service or client method like this (if your are just reading from DB then set `withTransaction` to `false`, you don't need a transaction in that case):

   ```
    using(var uow = new UnitOfWork("place_your_conn_string", withTransaction: true))
    {
        var countB = await uow.PostgreSqlRepositoryB.GetCountB();

        uow.PostgreSqlRepositoryB.SaveSomethingToA("123456");

        uow.Commit();
    }
   ```

Comment: Your answer helped me along with this problem but I went with something a bit different than the actual pattern. It's just a detail but I don't think your code calls `Dispose` on `NpgsqlCommand` (I'm not even sure if the dispose is needed if you dispose of the connection?). Should I post my solution? I don't use stackoverflow too often

Comment: The code I gave you above is just to give you direction, you can edit or improve it as you want. But, I have updated the `UnitOfWork` code to make the Disposable pattern better and also the `NpsqlCommand` is now under `using` so it will be disposed when the repo method returns. That way it's explicitly disposed and you are safe.